# Filter out elements by comparing a list of strings and a map

Tags: scala

I have two functions which get a list of Strings and a Map as parameters and return a list of Integers. As shown:

```
def f1(names: List[String], namemap: Map[String, List[Int]]): List[Int] = 

def f2(names: List[String], namemap: Map[String, List[Int]]): List[Int] =
```

To make the following explanation more understandable here is an example:

```
val nameslist = List("alex", "toby")

val namesmap = Map("sarah" -> List(5), "toby" -> List(6), "alex" -> List(1, 6))

println(f1(nameslist, namesmap))
//should print: List(6,1)
println(f2(nameslist, namesmap))
//should print: List(6)
```

The function `f1` should "compare"? the Strings from the List `namelist` with the Strings from the Map `namesmap` and returns all the Integer values from `namesmap` where the String is found.

The function `f2` should only return the Integers which are found in both Strings.

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem? Can you give us your partial solution? Thanks :)

Comment: This is the first time I am dealing with this kind of problem and I am quite lost where to start here! Any tips on what I should research?

Comment: This be pretty easy to solve using `map` and `foldLeft` on the names **List** and `getOrElse` in the names **Map**; check the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/). Also, you want to check on the **Set** class ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help.

```
val nameslist = List("alex", "toby", "jo")
val namesmap =
  Map("sarah" -> List(5), "toby" -> List(6), "alex" -> List(1, 6))

nameslist.flatMap(namesmap.get)  //List[List[Int]]
         .flatten                //List[Int]
         .distinct               //duplicates removed
//res0: List[Int] = List(1, 6)

nameslist.flatMap(namesmap.get)       //List[List[Int]]
         .reduceOption(_ intersect _) //Option[List[Int]]
         .getOrElse(Nil)              //List[Int]
//res1: List[Int] = List(6)
```

Comment: This is good! Thanks heaps mate! Only thing is, when I try `f2(List("alex", "jo"),namesmap)`it still returns `List (1,6)` even though `"jo"` doesn't exist in `namesmap`

Comment: I figured it out! thanks!
`if (nameslist.map(namesmap.get).forall(_.isDefined))`
...
`else List()`